# GWT StackPanel limitation?

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a component like the StackPanel or DecoratedStackPanel that has the ability of showing more than one panel in the stack at a time? Id like to have the option of expanding all or collapsing any number of the panels I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since I got no answer, this is what has worked for me. Google doesn't make it real easy to extend existing panels to add or modify functionality, so what I did was I downloaded the source, copied `StackPanel.java`, `DecoratorPanel.java` and `DecoratedStackPanel.java` into a package in my gwt project.

The main change I really needed to do was to change the behavior of the `showStack(int index)` in the `StackPanel.java` class from

```
  public void showStack(int index) {
    if ((index >= getWidgetCount()) || (index < 0) || (index == visibleStack)) {
      return;
    }

    if (visibleStack >= 0) {
      setStackVisible(visibleStack, false);
    }

    visibleStack = index;
    setStackVisible(visibleStack, true);    }
```

to something like this:

```
 public void showStack(int index) {

    if ((index >= getWidgetCount()) || index < 0) {
       return;
    }

    visibleStack = index;
    setStackVisible(visibleStack, !getWidget(visibleStack).isVisible());


  }
```

I'm sure it's possible to clean this up a bit, but this did the trick. 
The reason the other classes need to be copied over to the same package is because `StackPanel.java` references some of their methods that only have package visibility.

Comment: In GWT 2.5 there was no need to copy the other classes any longer.